Getting "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed" While using HTTPX and ThreadPoolExecutor in my Python Script
So, I am trying to port my script from requests to httpx as the one with the requests is failing on websites protected by Cloudflare and despite my best efforts, I am not able to fix it. Besides, for fun, I wanted to test if the async will improve the speed.
So, what my script does is scan an entire WordPress website for broken links and add them in a CSV file.
I was using ThreadPoolExecutor in this to check all links found in a post in one go rather than looping through it.
Now, I want to do the same thing using Asyncio/Httpx.
So, I tried it like this:
import httpx
import asyncio
import bs4
import sys
import csv
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import as_completed

headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'dnt': '1',
        'priority': 'u=0, i',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15 Edg/126.0.0.0'
    }
    
async def threadWorkAsync(link, headers, client):
        print("\t Content Link:", link[0], end=" ")
        try:
            link_response= await client.head(link[0], headers=headers)
            print(link_response.status_code)
        except (
            httpx.HTTPStatusError,
            httpx.HTTPError,
            httpx.ConnectError,
            httpx.InvalidURL,
            httpx.ConnectTimeout,
            httpx.RequestError,
        ) as errh:
            print("{errh} in URL, ", link)    

def asyncThreadRunner(link, headers, client):
     # Create run loop for this thread and block until completion
     asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
     asyncio.run(threadWorkAsync(link, headers, client))

def executeBrokenLinkCheck(links, client):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(asyncThreadRunner, link, headers, client) for link in links]
        return [future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
    
    
def get_pages(domain):
    pages = int( httpx.get("https://" + domain + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", headers=headers).headers["X-WP-TotalPages"] )
    return pages

def getLinks(rendered_content):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(rendered_content, "html.parser")
    return [(link["href"], link.text) for link in soup("a") if "href" in link.attrs]

async def fetch_posts(url):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
            return

        data = response.json()
        for post in data:
            post_link = post['link']
            print("Post Link:", post_link, end=" ")

            # Check the status of the post link
            link_response = await client.head(post_link, headers=headers)
            print(link_response.status_code)
            
            # Get links from post content
            links = getLinks(post['content']['rendered'])
            executeBrokenLinkCheck(links, client)

async def main():
    base_url = sys.argv[1]
    
    pages = get_pages(base_url)
    
    print(pages)

    # Iterate through 10 pages, assuming 10 posts per page
    for page in range(1, pages+1):
        url = f"https://{base_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page={page}"
        print(url)
        print(f"Fetching posts from page {page}...")
        await fetch_posts(url)

asyncio.run(main())

But it giving this error...
  File "C:\python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

After I looked it up then found out that it can be prevented by using this:
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
Now, after adding this line in the asyncThreadRunner, the script pauses in between and never resumes. Even pressing Ctrl+C doesn't quit it. I have to manually end it from the TasK Manager.
How do I fix this?

asyncio.run is called in the asyncThreadRunner scope and in the module scope. It should only be called once in the same thread.
executeBrokenLinkCheck should be a coroutine. It should submit threadWorkAsync directly to the thread pool executor.
Then have the main event loop gather the coroutines as soon as they complete and are yielded.
async def executeBrokenLinkCheck(links, client):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(threadWorkAsync, link, headers, client)
            for link in links
        ]
        await asyncio.gather(*[future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)])

Also remember to await the executeBrokenLinkCheck coroutine.
